Pyspark 3.5 : Databricks 14.3 ML LTS Run time gives different results for the same code
I am running below code on Databricks 14.3 ML LTS cluster. I am performing a validation task for the code migration from Databricks 10.4 ML LTS to 14.3 ML LTS.
window_c = (
        Window()
        .partitionBy("outlet_id")
        .orderBy("year_month")
        .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
    )

distinct_combination_count = (
master_keys
  .withColumn("distributor_id", f.last("distributor_id", True).over(window_c))
  .select("item_id","distributor_id")
  .distinct()
  .count()
)

for validation purposes on two clusters, I need to get the unique combination of item_id and distributor_id. But everytime I ran above snippet I am getting different results in both clusters. (I have run the code snipper multiple time in same cluster and got different results).
Any help would be appreciated.
I would also like to know whether anyone noticed any other major differences in results when run code in Databricks 10.4 vs 14.3 LTS.

Provide the sample data you are using.

Check if the data is consistent. there is nothing wrong in the code..

Data is consistent. There are instances with null values in the distributor id column.

Then you do filter and remove null records. is ouccuring after transformation or before?

This only starts to occur after f.last() operation which will help to reduce null values in distributor id

Provide the sample data it would help to reproduce the isssue.

To obtain consistent results for the unique combination of "item_id" and "distributor_id" across different clusters, I attempted the approach below:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = [
    (1, "A", "2022-01-01"),
    (2, "B", "2022-01-01"),
    (3, None, "2022-01-01"),
    (1, "A", "2022-02-01"),
    (2, "B", "2022-02-01"),
    (3, "C", "2022-02-01"),
]

columns = ["item_id", "distributor_id", "year_month"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

window_c = (
    Window()
    .partitionBy("item_id")
    .orderBy("year_month")
    .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
)

filled_df = df.withColumn("filled_distributor_id", F.last("distributor_id", True).over(window_c))
distinct_combinations = filled_df.select("item_id", "filled_distributor_id").distinct()
distinct_combination_count = distinct_combinations.count()
distinct_combinations.show()
print("Distinct Combination Count:", distinct_combination_count)

In this code, I defined the window specification, filled null values in distributor_id with the last non-null value within each partition, obtained distinct combinations of item_id and distributor_id, and counted the distinct combinations.
Results:
+-------+---------------------+
|item_id|filled_distributor_id|
+-------+---------------------+
|      1|                    A|
|      2|                    B|
|      3|                 NULL|
|      3|                    C|
+-------+---------------------+

Distinct Combination Count: 4

